# Where can I find the JavaTestUtils and BatchCounter dependencies referenced in JavaMapWithStateSuite.java?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I found this java class https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/test/java/org/apache/spark/streaming/JavaMapWithStateSuite.java that I want to run the JUNIT tests on to familiarize myself with Spark State.

However, when I try to put this Java class into a new project in my IDE it can't resolve these two classes (presumably Java?):

- JavaTestUtils
- BatchCounter

Where can I find these classes to run these JUNIT tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, (unfortunately!?;) not java:

- [JavaTestUtils.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/JavaTestUtils.scala)
- and BatchCounter is defined in [TestSuiteBase.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/TestSuiteBase.scala)

---